# Open a project file in phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Howdy,
I have a project in VisualStudio which contains a folder 'xmlfiles' below the root node. This folder contains a file 'mensen.xml' which I try to open ...

However when I try to open that very file the debugger steps in and throws an exception.

I tried it with

            `if(File.Exists(@"/xmlfiles/mensen.xml") )
            {
                bool exists = true;
            }
as well as:`

```
        FileStream fs = File.Open("/xmlfiles/mensen.xml", FileMode.Open);            
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fs);
        kantinen = (meineKantinen)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
```

Nothin is working :(.
How can I open a local file in the Phone7 Emulator?

Comment: Hi theXs, If your intention is to be able to modify this file, then copying it to isolated storage per ChrisKent's suggestion is good. If you only want to read the file there is no problem reading it from the xap file as either a content or resource (depending when you want to incur the load coast - lazy load vs startup respectively) as Ctacke and Matt suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just opening it to read it then you can do the following (Assuming you have set the Build Action of the file to Resource):

```
System.IO.Stream myFileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLY;component/xmlfiles/mensen.xml",UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
```

If you are attempting to read/write this file then you will need to copy it to Isolated Storage.  (Be sure to add `using System.IO.IsolatedStorage`)

You can use these methods to do so:

```
 private void CopyFromContentToStorage(String fileName)
 {
   IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
   System.IO.Stream src = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLY;component/" + fileName,UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
   IsolatedStorageFileStream dest = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, store);
   src.Position = 0;
   CopyStream(src, dest);
   dest.Flush();
   dest.Close();
   src.Close();
   dest.Dispose();
 }

 private static void CopyStream(System.IO.Stream input, IsolatedStorageFileStream output)
 {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
   long TempPos = input.Position;
   int readCount;
   do
   {
     readCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     if (readCount > 0) { output.Write(buffer, 0, readCount); }
   } while (readCount > 0);
   input.Position = TempPos;
 }
```

In both cases, be sure the file is set to Resource and you replace the YOURASSEMBLY part with the name of your assembly.

Using the above methods, to access your file just do this:

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (!store.FileExists(fileName))
{
  CopyFromContentToStorage(fileName);
}
store.OpenFile(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Append);
```

Answer (score 0):

The emulator does not have access to the PC file system.  You must deploy the file to the target (emulator).  The easiest way to do this is mark the file as an embedded Resource.  Set the file's Build Action to 'Resource' and then extract it at runtime with code something like this:

```
var res = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri([nameOfYourFile], UriKind.Relative))
```

Comment: If explicitly accessing/loading the file like this (and only this), set the Build Action to "Content". Doing so will prevent the resource being loaded when the app starts and thereby helping your launch-time performance.